# Red light from headphone jack Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, macbook, jack

I'm getting a red light from the audio jack on a 2012 Macbook Pro. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Sound works fine, headphones or speakers, but whenever the sound is on the light comes on. It usually turns off when the sound does (but not always, or immediately)

Comment: Does this happen on OS X? I think the headphone jack may also be a optical output.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using ubuntu-16.04 and after so many attempts I figured out the solution.

These are the steps to **solve red light audio jack issue in Macbook**.

1. open **system settings**.
2. go to **output** tab, select **speakers - Built-in Audio** option
   under **Play sound through** category.
3. look for the **mode** option under **settings for speakers** category.
4. Change mode from **Analog Stereo Output** to **Analog Surround 2.1 Output** or **Analog Surround 4.1 Output**.

[image]
Enjoy!

Comment: That disables all audio output for me on a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Comment: That's weird. I've MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the red light you're seeing is in fact the optical audio data. The headphone jack output on your Macbook Pro doubles as an optical out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable IEC958 options. Download QASmixer as instructed in this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNI485CczNQ

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that sakell's solution above works on ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a macbook pro a1502 (year 2014), where the solution of installing QasMixer is in the youtube video link given by sakell:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNI485CczNQ

For a macbook pro, a1502 (2014), I tried many solutions including directly using alsa mixer, etc, and editing files and directory settings, but none of them worked to turn off the red light that would turn on at the headphone port for the digital optical audio output, when there was no digital audio used, and when the ubuntu sound settings were all set to analog output speakers.

Here are more details, where this solution that has worked permanently for weeks and is still working.  It involves turning off the digital portion of the hw card (cirrus logic device in this case), and not changing the other hardware card or usb sound settings.

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS linux, I installed Qas mixer:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qasmixer
```

(1)  Run Qas Mixer, and on the right side of the window, look for 'Mixer device' and select 'hw - card' and look through the 0:  1:  and 2: , etc, options, for the different audio devices for the sound card and usb audio devices.

(2) Find and select the hardware device that controls the digital audio, and in my case this was the:  cirrus logic (1:) card

(3) Uncheck the lower left check box to 'iec958'

(4) Uncheck the lower left check box to  'iec958 default pcm'

Note:  In my case 'hda intell Haswell' hardware card 0: does have all 5 of the boxes checked

- The red laser light has now finally stopped turning on randomly and stays off.